# How to pull artifact version in udeploy from a custom url

Tags: teamcity, urbancode, udeploy

I am very new to udeploy and looking for a feature to pull latest version of artifacts from one of our build tool using simple http download from a given url.

I can see that "Source Configuration Type" has many option available like filesystem, teamcity, git repo etc, but no option is available for a simple url download.

I am actually using teamcity build and teamcity provides GET API to download artifacts, I understand that uDeoploy is also using this teamcity feature but the url it is constructing is not correct and throwing 401 exception (unauthorized) when not auth information is not provided, it should be using teamcity guest access to download the artifacts.

Please Note:  when login information is provided it is working fine

any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `guest` account privileges inside the `Administration Panel`, then inside the Users management, there is a link to setuo the guest account privileges.

Comment: do not have that much privilege to update guest account in teamcity